# Override PDF invoice coupon discount

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, pdf

I cannot found function to override (and relative core magento file) for edit total invoice coupon discount
I need to print discount value vat excluded

[image]

Comment: Do you want to customize invoice pdf only, right?

Comment: yes i need to print discount code without tax vat but i cannot found method / file to override